# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Null selected

Tags: c#

I have a problem when i convert Combo Box to an object named Category
Category selected = cb.SelectedItem as Category;
selected always return null [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSv1P.png)enter image description here
Can somebody can explain and fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH0Bx.png)

Comment: Well, is looks like `SelectedItem` is not a `Category` instance. Use the debugger to look at `SelectedItem` and see what type is actually is.

Comment: class Category
    {
        public Category(int id, string name)
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public Category(DataRow row)
        {
            this.ID = (int)row["id"];
            this.Name = row["name"].ToString();
        }
        private int iD;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return iD; }
            set { iD = value; }
        }
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
 }